# How To Improve?

Tags: health, skills

Could it really be possible for a rider, like me (who is fat but loves cycling) to improve his skills and gain stability for riding a good mile? If Yes, How?

Comment: I assume you mean *improve* and not *improvise*. Yes, and we've got [quite a lot of questions on the subject under the *beginner* tag](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beginner?mixed=1)

Comment: The only thing you need to do is to get on a bike and ride.  That single set of actions puts you ahead of everyone else who doesn't/can't/won't ride.   And do it again the next day.... repeat.

Comment: What do you mean by "ride a good mile"?  Do you mean being able to go a mile, or do you mean improving your speed in sprinting a mile?  Either way, the answer is still yes.  The human body has an amazing ability to strengthen and become more capable in response to repeated stress of appropriate difficulty -- not too easy, not too hard -- with appropriate rest and nutrition.  You can think of it as signaling or sending a message to your body: when you repeatedly stress your body, you're telling it, this is something you want to get better at.  And then you do.

Comment: just gotta keep riding

Answer (score 3):

Yes, stick to it and keep doing it, each time will get you that much closer to your goal. It is very possible, start slow and stay dedicated.

Answer (score 2):

I actually am jealous of where you are! At your stage of training, you will see *enormous* improvements in your fitness and athletic performance by any measure you like, in a short period of time and without much effort. I haven't seen 100% or 200% improvements in anything in a six month period in probably 20 years.

At the stage I'm at, on the other hand, I have to put in a Herculean effort to see even small performance gains. Thankfully, I bike because I like it. :)